# Result in a drop down format not displaying in html using ajax and jquery in laravel7

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am trying to choose a town from the database depending on the city that has been chosen from a drop down. I am following the data-dependent concept. This is the html code for the city and town form fields below:

```
                             <div class="col-md-6 form-group p_star">
                                <label for="region" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">{{ __('Region:') }}</label>
                                <select type="text" class="country_select form-control @error('region') is-invalid @enderror dynamic" id="region" name="region" value="{{ old('region') }}" data-dependent="town" required autocomplete="region">
                                    <option value="">Select Region</option>
                                    @foreach($regions as $region)
                                        <option value="{{ $region->region }}" {{ old('region') == $region->region ? 'selected' : ''}}>{{$region->region}}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                                @error('region')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6 form-group p_star">
                                <label for="town" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">{{ __('District/Town/Area:') }}</label>
                                <select name="town" type="text" id="town" class="country_select form-control @error('town') is-invalid @enderror">
                                    <option value="">Select Town</option>
                                </select>
                                @error('town')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
```

My issue is that after I choose the city, ajax gets a result of towns under that city but will not display them in html in a drop down manner. Nothing is displayed although you can see the contents of the result on the chrome console. Below is my jquery and ajax code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.dynamic').change(function(){
        if($(this).val() != '')
        {
            var select = $(this).attr("id");
            var value = $(this).val();
            var dependent = $(this).data('dependent');
            var _token = $('input[name = "_token"]').val();
            $.ajax({
                url:"{{route('UserController.fetch')}}",
                method:"POST",
                data:{select:select, value:value, _token:_token, dependent:dependent},
                success:function(result)
                {
                    $('#'+dependent).html(result);
                }
            })
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

I tried changing `$('#'+dependent).html(result)` to `$('#test').val(result)` whereby the `#test` was a normal input field and the result displayed there as well. I'm not sure whether the issue could be with `.html` within `$('#'+dependent).html(result)`, but it all doesn't make sense. Please help me out here.

Comment: does `dependent` has right value ? your code seems ok to me .

Comment: Yes it had the right value. I figured out the issue. The code is fine. The issue was with the CSS that I realized under the inspect element. The drop down that was supposed to be displayed had CSS display as none. Thank you